# Profiling applications using DI containers, anonymous methods or LINQ queries

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, profiling, unity-container, anonymous-function

I find myself trying to profile an application we recently developed using latest technologies and I'm having a hard time with several things:

1. I cannot profile constructors as we are using Unity and inversion of control and seems that everything is worked out through reflection so I really don't know what's going on. I only see high times on Unity when creating objects.
2. The code has a nice amount of anonymous methods and again it is difficult to profile them. Any hint on how to identify and profile them?
3. LINQ queries are difficult to profile too. Is there a specific tool to profile them?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). If you need to profile the constructors that are auto-wired by Unity, it means that your constructor do too much. Injection constructors should be simple.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the problem. I expect the constructors to be lightweight but we are a medium team and there are more than 200KLOC so I would like to verify that they don't do other things. I expected to use a profiler to find out any incorrect usage.